# Macbook Pro Retina 2014 - Quick return from Sleep - Black screen with cursor before login window

Tags: display, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I just got a MBPr. When the display switches off, like its going to sleep and I quickly hit a key to wake it back up. It shows a black screen with a cursor for about 15-20 seconds before the login screen appears. Its only if I do it instantly after the screen switches off. If I leave it off for sometime it comes back instantly...

Its not a problem when I don't log back in and let the screen go black from the login prompt.

I also tried to totally disable the show login screen after screensaver/sleep option and it still take a while to go from black to my desktop.

This is a problem if I have an external display plugged in or no displays attached. Its really annoying because I want to stop it from sleeping because I'm reading or something.

Is this normal? How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: I too have a very similar problem, whenever my screen turns off and I quickly touch a key to bring it back, it comes back to a black screen + cursor for ~5-10 seconds. I'm not running multiple displays, nor am I using Spotify. I've just purchased the computer and it's been doing it since day 1.

Comment: Ran into the same issue on Yosemite. For me it was Adobe Creative Cloud in the toolbar. Killing this process solved my issue.

Comment: Not answering the question, but look up an app called Caffeine. Puts a little icon in the menu bar that you can click to keep the screen awake for x minutes.

Comment: Me to experiencing this from day one (retina mid 2014, Mavericks to Yosemite). Found the reason here: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/unusual-wake-up-from-sleep-behavior-for-late-2013-15-rmbp.1731381/page-2#post-19172071
It's a bug in Message screen saver without a message. I say it's a bug, because we are waking the computer, so wtf is screensaver kicking in at all!? And it doesn't kick in (login is shown) if it's set to anything else than Message.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out in this case the cause is Spotify. It seems to be a bug with the Spotify app. Yet no bug fix has been released. If you have spotify running, kill it and see if you get this issue still.

If you dont use Spotify go through a process of elimination. Start by killing everything running (processes/background/tray tasks) then make the laptop it sleeps and comes back.

Then start processes/background/tray tasks up one by one and let the computer sleep (change it to 1 minute or something to test) then see if it comes back ok. Keep going until it doesn't thats the process at fault.

Comment: I have this same problem, but I do not have Spotify. Any other ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: No spotify here as well. Someone with a different suggestion?

Comment: I dond't have spotify either...

Comment: Go through a process of elimination kill everything running make sure it works, then start processes up one by one and let the computer sleep (change it to 1 minute or something to test) then see if it comes back ok.

Comment: Yosemite should be out in a week or so which might fix this issue too.

Comment: It may not be specifically Spotify that is causing this... or rather, in your case it may be Spotify, but the behaviour it is having could be shared by other apps.
You mentioned that it only happens if you immediately wake system as soon as it goes to sleep, but not if the system has been asleep for several minutes or more. This would indicate that the computer is still saving the contents of the RAM to Macintosh HD when you wake again. Spotify may have been impacting how long this took for you by not responding to the system going to sleep fast enough <continued in next comment>

Comment: So when when the system started trying to save the contents of your RAM to Macintosh HD, it was slowed down by Spotify acting as if the system was still normally awake. The reason then that it wouldn't occur when the system has been asleep for a while already was that that whole process had now had time to complete anyway and when you work it from sleep, it wasn't halfway through a task that it needed to complete before resuming what you wanted it to be doing.

Comment: @brandt, Birowsky and Pier, you guys should go through your startup items and non-Apple apps to see if disabling any particular one may be having the same effect as Spotify was having on the OP's system. As I said in my first comment, while it has been isolated to being caused by Spotify on the OP's Mac, a different app or background service could be misbehaving the same way on your system too!

Comment: The bug is in the SpotifyWebHelper program located in ~/Library/Application Support/Spotify/SpotifyWebHelper. I deleted the contents of this file in TextEdit and locked it (using "Get Info") in order to stop it from being re-generated.